# Any online course using Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Any online course (Coursera, EdX, MIT Open Courseware, etc...) which have a curriculum following [Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321797094)? I like to have an option to fall back on in case there is something that is difficult to digest in the book - specifically, video lectures.

Answer (score 1):

The Great Courses company has a course called "Prove It: The Art of Mathematical Argument". Unfortunately, it is not free. However, it does a good job of clearly explaining what one should learn in an introductory proof course.

Comment: just to help anyone that stumble on this answer: the course referenced is not using the book in question, at least there is no indication that it follows the book in the course description. the course seems to be self contained.